# Where is the log of pppd in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, log, pppoe, debug

I am trying to find the debug infromation of pppd on Ubuntu 13.10. I have tried to read the mannual, but I found that the location of the log is for older version Ubuntu.

what I have input

```
sudo pon dsl-provider debug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see pppd logs in /var/log/syslog

```
less /var/log/syslog
```

or

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

or

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: There are too many logs. Is it possible to rule out irrelevant information?

Comment: only can grep some thing `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep ppp` or `less /var/log/syslog | grep ppp`

Comment: How can I use plog to print more information?

Comment: By the manual  `plog shows you the last few lines of  /var/log/ppp.log.  If  that  file
       doesn't  exist, it shows you the last few lines of your /var/log/syslog
       file, but excluding the lines not generated by pppd.  This script makes
       use  of the tail(1) command, so arguments that can be passed to tail(1)
       can also be passed to plog.` Same thing on another please. Simple run plog in console and plog will grep pppd log from syslog.

Answer (score 2):

From pppd man pages:

```
   debug  Enables  connection  debugging  facilities.   If  this option is
          given, pppd will log the contents of all control packets sent or
          received  in  a  readable  form.  The packets are logged through
          syslog with facility daemon and level debug.   This  information
          can  be  directed  to  a  file  by  setting  up /etc/syslog.conf
          appropriately (see syslog.conf(5)).
```

So by default all the `pppd` logs will be redirected to `/var/log/syslog`.